# I've seen these movies countless ties

Tags: wordplay, movies

I wanted to make a puzzle for you all with some help from my friends so I dictated a list of my favourite movies to Paul and he typed them up. He then gave the list to Alice to describe the titles.

I looked at Alice's list and I was initially confused, because her sentences didn't describe my film titles. Then it became apparent that the keyboard Paul had used wasn't working very well. Every item on my list had been typed with a single letter missing. Of course the spellchecker didn't pick up on it, because every title still made sense.

I've reproduced Alice's list here with the year of the film and the missing letter.

1. B (2009): One cereal grain that knows how to party.
2. C (2006): Footwear jottings.
3. E (1967): Do you wear that to sleep in? Your head must get hot.
4. E (1981): My mum's an angel, but he's completely different.
5. E (2011): The fish that spawned all the rest.
6. G (1975): He wants to marry into our family.
7. G (1977): You aren't allowed to marry that many women. You'll be one over the limit.
8. H (1993): That's a lot of fuss to make about some shorthand.
9. H (1994): I know that tombstones don't exactly look healthy, but this one is terrible. It's yellow too.
10. I (1964): I have many girlfriends, but this one takes the longest to get to.
11. I (1979): A tale of the outer layer of a cereal grain.
12. I (1996): I filed for protection of my invention in London.
13. K (1967): I was walking through the forest and someone surprised me with an exclamation.
14. L (1959): She's gorgeous, but those sores haven't healed yet.
15. L (1985): A baby bear who eats with us every morning.
16. L (1990): Joseph's father had a snake.
17. L (1994): Stories about young dogs.
18. L (1995): The corpse appears to be stirring. He's not asleep.
19. M (1991): The researchers have gone home - it's so quiet.
20. N (1954): The lady at the back has lost her husband.
21. N (1973): It's the bloke off Top Gear.
22. N (1973): Pay attention, Dorothy.
23. N (1977): My youngest child has met a lot of strangers. The other two haven't.
24. N (1990): Only use this shed if you are in Russia in the middle of autumn.
25. N (2002): Manhattan comedy.
26. N (2012): These competitions are bigger than last time.
27. O (1971): That's a big cooker. How long does it take to wind it up?
28. O (1989): All they do is talk about their deceased animals.
29. O (1992): Not many ministers.
30. P (1983): It would look better if we took the red ones from your shoes and swapped them with the black ones in mine.
31. R (1930): These mass baptisms are really noisy, but the minister furthest from the sunrise has everything under control.
32. R (1969): He's a real pain in the neck.
33. R (1982): Knuckle gore.
34. R (2002): Less than half the people are planting up their seedlings.
35. R (2008): His electrons and protons don't match.
36. S (1977): Battles over bitumen.
37. S (1992): Her only coin.
38. S (1995): A Conservative that you play with.
39. S (2000): Missing feline.
40. S (2004): When he passed away, all he left us were these garden tools.
41. T (1953): The god of shepherds in the House of Lords.
42. T (1955): A women encounters a change of gradient.
43. T (1968): Do those monkeys fly that thing?
44. T (1986): I don't like it at the beach. This stuff makes me uncomfortable.
45. U (1955): He'd cause a lot more trouble if he had some luggage!
46. U (1978): We use it to wash all the creatures.

**Question:** Can you work out the titles as Alice saw them, and how they should have been?

Comment: Is the misspelling of "times" intentional?

Comment: @JoeZ.  Paul typed it using the same keyboard as he did for the list. We really need a new keyboard.

Comment: This is wonderful!

Comment: This puzzle is awesome. +1 for sure. I think there's a typo at the beginning though, 'so I dictated a list of my favourite puzzles to Paul' I assume you mean movies/titles

Comment: @NeedAName well spotted.

Comment: Should the spell checker have caught Manhatten/Manhattan?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Yes!

Comment: These are very funny, I love #13 in particular!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. B (2009): One cereal grain that knows how to party.

   > **The (B)oat That Rocked**
2. C (2006): Footwear jottings.

   > **Notes on a S(c)andal**
3. E (1967): Do you wear that to sleep in? Your head must get hot.

   > **In the H(e)at of the Night**
4. E (1981): My mum's an angel, but he's completely different.

   > **The Evil D(e)ad**
5. E (2011): The fish that spawned all the rest.

   > **Source Cod(e)**
6. G (1975): He wants to marry into our family.

   > **The Man Who Would Be Kin(g)**
7. G (1977): You aren't allowed to marry that many women. You'll be one over the limit.

   > **A Brid(g)e Too Far**
8. H (1993): That's a lot of fuss to make about some shorthand.

   > **Much Ado About Not(h)ing**
9. H (1994): I know that tombstones don't exactly look healthy, but this one is terrible. It's yellow too.

   > **S(h)allow Grave**
10. I (1964): I have many girlfriends, but this one takes the longest to get to.

    > **My Fa(i)r Lady**
11. I (1979): A tale of the outer layer of a cereal grain.

    > **Monty Python's Life of Br(i)an**
12. I (1996): I filed for protection of my invention in London.

    > **The English Pat(i)ent**
13. K (1967): I was walking through the forest and someone surprised me with an exclamation.

    > **The Jungle Boo(k)**
14. L (1959): She's gorgeous, but those sores haven't healed yet.

    > **S(l)eeping Beauty**
15. L (1985): A baby bear who eats with us every morning.

    > **Breakfast C(l)ub**
16. L (1990): Joseph's father had a snake.

    > **Jacob's (L)adder**
17. L (1994): Stories about young dogs.

    > **Pu(l)p Fiction**
18. L (1995): The corpse appears to be stirring. He's not asleep.

    > **The Wa(l)king Dead**
19. M (1991): The researchers have gone home - it's so quiet.

    > **The Silence of the La(m)bs**
20. N (1954): The lady at the back has lost her husband.

    > **Rear Wi(n)dow**
21. (1973): It's the bloke off Top Gear.

    > **The Sti(n)g**
22. N (1973): Pay attention, Dorothy.

    > **Do(n')t Look Now**
23. N (1977): My youngest child has met a lot of strangers. The other two haven't. '

    > **Close Encounters of the Third Ki(n)d**
24. N (1990): Only use this shed if you are in Russia in the middle of autumn.

    > **The Hu(n)t for Red October**
25. N (2002): Manhattan comedy.

    > **Ga(n)gs of New York**
26. N (2012): These competitions are bigger than last time.

    > **The Hu(n)ger Games**
27. O (1971): That's a big cooker. How long does it take to wind it up?

    > **A Clockwork (O)range**
28. O (1989): All they do is talk about their deceased animals.

    > **Dead P(o)ets Society**
29. O (1992): Not many ministers.

    > **A Few Go(o)d Men**
30. P (1983): It would look better if we took the red ones from your shoes and swapped them with the black ones in mine.

    > **Trading (P)laces**
31. R (1930): These mass baptisms are really noisy, but the minister furthest from the sunrise has everything under control.

    > **All Quiet on the Western F(r)ont**
32. R (1969): He's a real pain in the neck.

    > **True G(r)it**
33. R (1982): Knuckle gore.

    > **Fi(r)st Blood**
34. R (2002): Less than half the people are planting up their seedlings.

    > **Minority Repo(r)t**
35. R (2008): His electrons and protons don't match.

    > **I(r)on Man**
36. S (1977): Battles over bitumen.

    > **(S)tar Wars**
37. S (1992): Her only coin.

    > **(S)cent of a Woman**
38. S (1995): A Conservative that you play with.

    > **Toy (S)tory**
39. S (2000): Missing feline.

    > **Ca(s)t Away**
40. S (2004): When he passed away, all he left us were these garden tools.

    > **Dead Man's (S)hoes**
41. T (1953): The god of shepherds in the House of Lords.

    > **Pe(t)er Pan**
42. T (1955): A women encounters a change of gradient.

    > **Lady and the (T)ramp**
43. T (1968): Do those monkeys fly that thing?

    > **Plane(t) of the Apes**
44. T (1986): I don't like it at the beach. This stuff makes me uncomfortable.

    > **S(t)and By Me**
45. U (1955): He'd cause a lot more trouble if he had some luggage!

    > **Rebel Without a Ca(u)se**
46. U (1978): We use it to wash all the creatures.

    > **Animal Ho(u)se**

Comment: Can anyone figure out spoilers and bold with this list?

Comment: This seems to be [a known issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266487). One suggested workaround is to [spoiler each item individually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266494) (leaving the number unhidden).

Answer (score 5):

Can someone point me to the wiki so that I can add these as I find them? I will be updating as I find more.

5: The fish that spawned all the others.

> Source Code/Cod

8: That's a lot of fuss to make about some shorthand.

> Much Ado About Nothing/Noting

11:A tale of the outer layer of a cereal grain.

> Monty Python's Life of Brian/Bran

21: It's the bloke off Top Gear.

> The Sting/Stig

29: Not many ministers.

> A Few Good/God Men

31: These mass baptisms are really noisy, but the minister furthest from the sunrise has everything under control.

> All Quiet on the Western Front/Font

33: Knuckle gore.

> First/Fist Blood

37: Her only coin.

> Scent/Cent of a Woman

Answer (score 4):

Here's ones that I've got (as a separate answer, I'll update the community wiki with them too):

```
 4. The Evil Dead (becomes "The Evil Dad")
12. The English Patient (becomes "The English Patent")
15. Breakfast Club (becomes "Breakfast Cub")
16. Jacob's Ladder (becomes "Jacob's Adder")
17. Pulp Fiction (becomes "Pup Fiction")
20. Rear Window (becomes "Rear Widow")
28. Dead Poets Society (becomes "Dead Pets Society")
30. Trading Places (becomes "Trading Laces")
35. Iron Man (becomes "Ion Man")
38. Toy Story (becomes "Toy Tory")
39. Cast Away (becomes "Cat Away")
46. Animal House (becomes "Animal Hose")
```

Funnily enough, for #39 I actually did find a movie in 2000 named "Lost Cat".