# Morse of the films that I've watched a lot

Tags: wordplay, movies

After my [last attempt](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22382/ive-seen-these-movies-countless-ties) to compile a movie list, we replaced Paul's keyboard and tried again.

Once again I dictated a list of my favourite movies to Paul and he typed them up. He then gave the list to Alice to describe the titles. I looked at Alice's list and it still wasn't right.

Then it became apparent that the new keyboard Paul had used was inserting extra random letters this time. Every item on my list had picked up one additional letter. Of course the spellchecker didn't pick up on it, because every title still made sense.

I've reproduced Alice's new list here with the year of the film and the extra letter.

```
B (1925): Sweeping with style.
B (1967): Young Skywalker tries to program his prosthetic.
B (1975): Was that a femur that you tossed over that tree? You almost hit that bird.
B (1981): All our cork trees have been stripped.
B (1988): Neurosurgeon.
B (1993): Furniture north of Manhattan.
C (1988): You will chop these vegetables until your hands hurt.
E (1935): I've soaked that pot almost 40 times and it still hasn't come clean!
E (1984): Use it to cover the hole left by a lumbar puncture.
F (1996): A girl's dress.
G (1987): A royal viaduct.
G (2012): Babe's biography.
H (1991): You fell asleep in the fireplace again, didn't you?
L (1966): Saints spend time with alopecia sufferers and their unattractive friends.
L (2008): Why can't we have REAL bullets for this mission?
L (2011): We mustn't avoid a discussion about nonnegative temperature designations.
M (1997): A military assault by rodents.
N (1946): The search engine is down for maintenance.
N (1980): Calculating distances the bovine way.
N (1992): Old boys and their ground beef
N (2010): Those women are trustworthy, but their husband's aren't.
O (1946): Our oily fruit are in their prime.
O (1949): Grumble, grumble, GRUMBLE.
O (1958): Why did you leave your parka up there? The sun has been shining on that metal all day.
P (1957): She loves me, loves me not, loves me, loves me not, loves me, loves me not, LOVES ME. Wait - you're supposed to do that with the petals.
P (1986): Find a title for my flowing text.
R (1956): We've been overrun by people who want to kidnap Amity's police chief.
R (1961): They pull strange faces on Leros.
R (1980): An amphibian
R (1984): It's harvest time near Hollywood.
R (1990): Marge, Bart, Lisa and Maggie have all gone out.
R (1991): Pickled flower phobia
R (1996): Let's go get the shrimp now.
S (1955): Moving trains from dusk to dawn.
S (1979): Nuclear winter.
S (1992): Let's play "Fortune Tellers".
S (1993): Prehistoric glimmer.
S (2012): You can't have any more samples of material.
T (1960): Mr Spielberg is fantastic.
T (2005): An interplanetary verruca.
U (1976): I'll eat every dish you prepared for the Obamas.
W (1995): An amphibian
W (2008): Pay the umpire to fix the match.
X (1973): Basket-weaving a cat with no tail.
Y (1941): An American rapper gets his passport.
```

**Question:** Can you work out the titles as Alice saw them, and how they should have been?

Comment: To start off (and provide an example) 1 - The Gold (B)rush

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. B (1925): Sweeping with style.

   > **The Gold (B)rush**
2. B (1967): Young Skywalker tries to program his prosthetic.

   > **Co(b)ol Hand Luke**
3. B (1975): Was that a femur that you tossed over that tree? You almost hit that bird.

   > **(B)one Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest**
4. B (1981): All our cork trees have been stripped.

   > **Raiders of the Lost (B)ark**
5. B (1988): Neurosurgeon.

   > **(B)rain Man**
6. B (1993): Furniture north of Manhattan.

   > **A Bronx Ta(b)le**
7. C (1988): You will chop these vegetables until your hands hurt.

   > **Di(c)e Hard**
8. E (1935): I've soaked that pot almost 40 times and it still hasn't come clean!

   > **The 39 St(e)eps**
9. E (1984): Use it to cover the hole left by a lumbar puncture.

   > **This Is Spinal Tap(e)**
10. F (1996): A girl's dress.

    > **The (F)rock**
11. G (1987): A royal viaduct.

    > **The Princess Brid(g)e**
12. G (2012): Babe's biography.

    > **Life of Pi(g)**
13. H (1991): You fell asleep in the fireplace again, didn't you?

    > **Night on (H)earth**
14. L (1966): Saints spend time with alopecia sufferers and their unattractive friends.

    > **The Good, the Ba(l)d, and the Ugly**
15. L (2008): Why can't we have REAL bullets for this mission?

    > **The B(l)ank Job**
16. L (2011): We mustn't avoid a discussion about nonnegative temperature designations.

    > **We Need to Talk About Ke(l)vin**
17. M (1997): A military assault by rodents.

    > **The (M)ice Storm**
18. N (1946): The search engine is down for maintenance.

    > **The Bi(n)g Sleep**
19. N (1980): Calculating distances the bovine way.

    > **Ra(n)ging Bull**
20. N (1992): Old boys and their ground beef.

    > **Of Mi(n)ce and Men**
21. N (2010): Those women are trustworthy, but their husband's aren't.

    > **Despicable Me(n)**
22. O (1946): Our oily fruit are in their prime.

    > **The Best Years of Our (O)lives**
23. O (1949): Grumble, grumble, GRUMBLE.

    > **The Third M(o)an**
24. O (1958): Why did you leave your parka up there? The sun has been shining on that metal all day.

    > **C(o)at on a Hot Tin Roof**
25. P (1957): She loves me, loves me not, loves me, loves me not, loves me, loves me not, LOVES ME. Wait - you're supposed to do that with the petals.

    > **The Seventh Se(p)al**
26. P (1986): Find a title for my flowing text.

    > **The Name of the (P)rose**
27. R (1956): We've been overrun by people who want to kidnap Amity's police chief.

    > **Invasion of the B(r)ody Snatchers**
28. R (1961): They pull strange faces on Leros.

    > **The Gu(r)ns of Navarone**
29. R (1980): An amphibian.

    > **The F(r)og**
30. R (1984): It's harvest time near Hollywood.

    > **Beverly Hills C(r)op**
31. R (1990): Marge, Bart, Lisa and Maggie have all gone out.

    > **Home(r) Alone**
32. R (1991): Pickled flower phobia.

    > **Cape(r) Fear**
33. R (1996): Let's go get the shrimp now.

    > **A Time to K(r)ill**
34. S (1955): Moving trains from dusk to dawn.

    > **The Night of the (S)hunter**
35. S (1979): Nuclear winter.

    > **Apocalypse (S)now**
36. S (1992): Let's play "Fortune Tellers".

    > **The (S)crying Game**
37. S (1993): Prehistoric glimmer.

    > **Jurassic (S)park**
38. S (2012): You can't have any more samples of material.

    > **End of (S)watch**
39. T (1960): Mr Spielberg is fantastic.

    > **The Magnificent S(t)even**
40. T (2005): An interplanetary verruca.

    > **War(t) of the Worlds**
41. U (1976): I'll eat every dish you prepared for the Obamas.

    > **All the President's Men(u)**
42. W (1995): An amphibian.

    > **The Ne(w)t**
43. W (2008): Pay the umpire to fix the match.

    > **Let the Right One (W)in**
44. X (1973): Basket-weaving a cat with no tail.

    > **The Wicker Man(x)**
45. Y (1941): An American rapper gets his passport.

    > **Citizen Kan(y)e**

Comment: 40) Star war(t)s - revenge of the sith

Comment: 42) The ne(w)t -

Comment: 34) Night of the (s)hunter

Comment: 19) Ra(n)ging Bull?

Comment: Well done everyone.