# A lot of these firms were never watched by me

Tags: wordplay, movies

We [replaced Paul's keyboard](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22396/morse-of-the-films-that-ive-watched-a-lot) a second time, and this time I (not Gordon K) tried naming a bunch of movies that I hadn't ever watched, to see if that would help mitigate the keyboard curse.

Turns out, it only made it worse, because this time, the keyboard *swapped* out one letter for another, performing *both* the deletion and insertion at the same time.

The spellchecker never picked up on these either, because as usual, every movie title still made sense, even for the two titles in this list that aren't even in English (they of course didn't pass an English spell-check, but in their native languages). I've given here each letter that was in the original movie title, along with the letter that it was swapped with to the right.

1. 3 > 4 (2006) A score of scores.
2. A > E (1975) Followers of Yahweh.
3. A > I (1960) A silky cloth that covers one’s face.
4. B > C (2013) Wood that makes noise come April.
5. B > F (2007) A god who’s bad at English announces his plan to Noah.
6. C > S (1966) My sister’s monarch.
7. D > A (2011) The person who has a region of Spain printed on her.
8. D > B (2004) Gulf, at least two days from now.
9. D > P (2008) The person who harvests grain.
10. E > A (2006) An achievement of extraordinary gladness.
11. E > D (2010) A relationship created in December.
12. F > D (2003) A large plate.
13. G > B (1986) The piece of bread on a burger you put your fingers on.
14. G > D (1964) A treasure locator.
15. H > C (2007) A man-eating man floats up.
16. H > L (1927) We’ve put yeast in this bread six times already, and we have to do it again?
17. H > Y (2011) A sudden sharp cry.
18. I > O (1951) Everybody run! It’s an alien bikini bottom!
19. K > B (1921) Charlie Chaplin participates in an auction.
20. L > B (2005) A cemetery crew marches playing instruments.
21. L > W (1979) The man everyone mistook for Jesus has a spouse.
22. N > F (1935) There’s a row at the theatre.
23. N > M (1985) The squishy purple balls that are dragon Pokémon.
24. N > S (2010) A film about the New World.
25. N > W (2014) A fox who steals things from the United States.
26. O > A (1976) Ending of a prayer.
27. O > G (1971) A monastic farm that runs extremely systematically.
28. O > S (2014) A film all about what animals use to walk.
29. P > H (2009) [makes a sound indicating unsureness]
30. P > T (1978) They really dilute stuff.
31. R > D (1950) That’s a big god.
32. R > N (1945) Each step is a vertebra.
33. R > N (2008) His armour is too damp.
34. R > U (2011) A mansion for combat.
35. R > V (1988) A narcissistic adult.
36. S > A (2006) The unfair actions of a corpse.
37. S > A (2013) A college full of swiss-cheese plants.
38. S > R (2009) I’m on a roller coaster and I can’t see anything!
39. S > T (2014) The mistake we made by beginning.
40. S > V (2014) A member of the Scooby Crew.
41. S > X (1968) A celestial ball with a peak-like structure.
42. T > D (2010) An instruction manual on siphoning bodily fluids out of a reptile.
43. T > G (1984) He makes plants grow.
44. T > K (2005) The turban-wearers strike back.
45. U > A (2012) Sports that gallows executioners play.
46. U > O (2006) My solemn promise to be faithful is causing extreme hassle.
47. Y > U (1986) Influenza.

Can you figure out what these titles are so that poor Alice doesn't have to retype them all?

Comment: @Gamow, I thought the title was intentional to match the puzzle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. 3 > 4 (2006) A score of scores.

   > (3/4)00
2. A > E (1975) Followers of Yahweh.

   > J(a/e)ws
3. A > I (1960) A silky cloth that covers one’s face.

   > The Mask of Sat(a/i)n
4. B > C (2013) Wood that makes noise come April.

   > Spring (B/C)reakers
5. B > F (2007) A god who’s bad at English announces his plan to Noah.

   > There Will Be (B/F)lood
6. C > S (1966) My sister’s monarch.

   > Le Roi de (C/S)œur
7. D > A (2011) The person who has a region of Spain printed on her.

   > The Girl with the (D/A)ragon Tattoo
8. D > B (2004) Gulf, at least two days from now.

   > The (D/B)ay After Tomorrow
9. D > P (2008) The person who harvests grain.

   > The Rea(d/p)er
10. E > A (2006) An achievement of extraordinary gladness.

    > Happy Fe(e/a)t
11. E > D (2010) A relationship created in December.

    > Winter's Bon(e/d)
12. F > D (2003) A large plate.

    > Big (F/D)ish
13. G > B (1986) The piece of bread on a burger you put your fingers on.

    > Top (G/B)un
14. G > D (1964) A treasure locator.

    > Goldfin(g/d)er
15. H > C (2007) A man-eating man floats up.

    > (H/C)annibal Rising
16. H > L (1927) We’ve put yeast in this bread six times already, and we have to do it again?

    > 7th (H/L)eaven
17. H > Y (2011) A sudden sharp cry.

    > The (H/Y)elp
18. I > O (1951) Everybody run! It’s an alien bikini bottom!

    > The Th(i/o)ng from Another World
19. K > B (1921) Charlie Chaplin participates in an auction.

    > The (K/B)id
20. L > B (2005) A cemetery crew marches playing instruments.

    > (L/B)and of the Dead
21. L > W (1979) The man everyone mistook for Jesus has a spouse.

    > Monty Python's (L/W)ife of Brian
22. N > F (1935) There’s a row at the theatre.

    > The (N/F)ight at the Opera
23. N > M (1985) The squishy purple balls that are dragon Pokémon.

    > The Goo(n/m)ies
24. N > S (2010) A film about the New World.

    > The America(n/s)
25. N > W (2014) A fox who steals things from the United States.

    > American S(n/w)iper
26. O > A (1976) Ending of a prayer.

    > The (O/A)men
27. O > G (1971) A monastic farm that runs extremely systematically.

    > A Clockwork (O/G)range
28. O > S (2014) A film all about what animals use to walk.

    > The Leg(o/s) Movie
29. P > H (2009) [makes a sound indicating unsureness]

    > U(p/h)
30. P > T (1978) They really dilute stuff.

    > Watershi(p/t) down
31. R > D (1950) That’s a big god.

    > (R/D)io Grande
32. R > N (1945) Each step is a vertebra.

    > The Spi(r\n)al Staircase
33. R > N (2008) His armour is too damp.

    > The Da(r/n)k Knight
34. R > U (2011) A mansion for combat.

    > War Ho(r/u)se
35. R > V (1988) A narcissistic adult.

    > (R/V)ain Man
36. S > A (2006) The unfair actions of a corpse.

    > Pirates of the Carribean: Dead Man's Che(s/a)t
37. S > A (2013) A college full of swiss-cheese plants.

    > Monster(s/a) University
38. S > R (2009) I’m on a roller coaster and I can’t see anything!

    > The Blind (S/R)ide
39. S > T (2014) The mistake we made by beginning.

    > The Fault in our Star(s/t)
40. S > V (2014) A member of the Scooby Crew.

    > (S/V)elma
41. S > X (1968) A celestial ball with a peak-like structure.

    > Planet of the Ape(s/x)
42. T > D (2010) An instruction manual on siphoning bodily fluids out of a reptile.

    > How to (T/D)rain Your Dragon
43. T > G (1984) He makes plants grow.

    > The (T/G)erminator
44. T > K (2005) The turban-wearers strike back.

    > Star Wars Episode III: Revenge of the Si(t/k)h
45. U > A (2012) Sports that gallows executioners play.

    > The H(u/a)nger Games
46. U > O (2006) My solemn promise to be faithful is causing extreme hassle.

    > An Inconvenient Tr(u/o)th
47. Y > U (1986) Influenza.

    > The Fl(y/u)

Comment: I guess these were too easy :(

Comment: It's really fun though, thanks for this! :)

Comment: @Joe: Easy doesn't necessarily mean bad! And I wouldn't have gotten most of these.

Comment: "The Dank Knight" oh god I'm dying here

Comment: @IanMacDonald Yep.

Comment: Think the list is now complete.